# Symfony2 dropdown form from database

Tags: php, symfony

So i want to display all the courses within my database in a drop down form. a user who is logged in then select one of the drop downs and it would store the users ID and the course ID into the database. How would i go about doing this?

Here's my course entity course.php

```
<?php
// src/Simple/SimpleBundle/Entity/Course.php
namespace Simple\ProfileBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="course")
*/
class Course
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="course", type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $course;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
}


   public function setCourse($course)
{
    $this->course = $course;
}

public function getCourse()
{
    return $this->course;
}

 public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
}
```

ChooseCourseType.php my form

```
<?php
// src/Simple/ProfileBundle/Controller/ChooseCourseType.php
namespace Simple\ProfileBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ChooseCourseType extends AbstractType
{
private $course;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {


$builder->add('course', 'choice', array(
    'choices'   => $this->course,
));

$builder->add('Choose Course', 'submit');

}
public function getName()
{
    return 'name';
}     
public function getCourse()
{
    return 'course';
}  



}
```

Coursecontroller.php

```
function chooseAction(Request $request)
{
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$form = $this->createForm(new ChooseCourseType(), $CourseType);

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    $course = $form->getData();

    $em->persist($course->getCourse());
    $em->flush();


}

return $this->render(
    'SimpleProfileBundle:Course:choosecourse.html.twig',
    array('form' => $form->createView())
);
}

}
```

User.php

```
namespace Simple\ProfileBundle\Entity;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="users")
*/
class User implements UserInterface
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="user", type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $salt;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_role",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $roles;

      /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Course")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_course",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="course_id",   
 referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $courses;
/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function getSalt()
{
    return '';
}

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function getRoles()
{
return $this->roles->toArray();
}

  /**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function eraseCredentials()
{
}

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->roles = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->salt = sha1(uniqid(null, true));
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set user
 *
 * @param string $user
 * @return User
 */
public function setUser($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get user
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}

/**
 * Set password
 *
 * @param string $password
 * @return User
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set salt
 *
 * @param string $salt
 * @return User
 */
public function setSalt($salt)
{
    $this->salt = $salt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Add roles
 *
 * @param \Simple\ProfileBundle\Entity\Role $roles
 * @return User
 */
public function addRole(\Simple\ProfileBundle\Entity\Role $roles)
{
    $this->roles[] = $roles;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove roles
 *
 * @param \Simple\ProfileBundle\Entity\Role $roles
 */
public function removeRole(\Simple\ProfileBundle\Entity\Role $roles)
{
    $this->roles->removeElement($roles);
}

    /**
 * Add roles
 *
 * @param \Simple\ProfileBundle\Entity\Course $courses
 * @return User
 */
public function addCourse(\Simple\ProfileBundle\Entity\Course $courses)
{
    $this->course[] = $courses;

    return $this;
}



}
```

What else am i missing i am new to symfony2 and just need some direction.

Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [symfony2 - adding choices from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836875/symfony2-adding-choices-from-database)

Comment: I read over that one and can't really apply it to my example or get my head around how i could do so, thanks

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the [entity form type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html).

**Form type**

```
<?php
// src/Simple/ProfileBundle/Controller/ChooseCourseType.php
namespace Simple\ProfileBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ChooseCourseType extends AbstractType {
    $builder->add('courses', 'entity', array(
        'label' => 'Courses',
        'class' => 'SimpleSimpleBundle:Course',
        'expanded' => false,
        'multiple' => false
    ))
    // ...
```

**Controller**

```
function chooseAction(Request $request) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    // Replace this with whatever logic you use to find the user
    $user = $em->getRepository('SimpleSimpleBundle:User')->findOneBy(
        array('id' => 1)
    );

    $form = $this->createForm(new ChooseCourseType(), $user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $user = $form->getData();

        // Since you've bound this user object to the form and properly
        // created a relationship between the course and user entities
        // the relationship between course and user will persist here
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

Comment: Is this all i am missing then ? Cheers

Comment: There are a few different ways to do this, but this is the simplest and seems to fit your use case. I would suggest reading about the various form types when you have some time.

Comment: I have read on it but i am just struggling to get my head around displaying them from the database and inserting the ID's into a table. Does my controller look right ? Cheers

Comment: It looks like you thinking about this a bit the wrong way. You want your form to modify your Course object (i.e. add a User to the Course), so that is what you need to pass as the second parameter to your form. You also need to create a relationship between User and Course in your Doctrine entities. You don't include the User entity here but I don't see any relationship in your Course entity. I do see you creating an ArrayCollection in the constructor but that's not sufficient.

Comment: I will show you the User entity, there is a relationship. So i pass the user object through the form? Cheers

Comment: I've expanded my answer based on the information you've added.