# Selected option in EntityType isn't checked in edit screen

Tags: php, symfony4

I've created a form field in a Symfony 4.2 Web Application based on an EntityType.

But i'm having some issues when editting the entry. The GUID ( i'm using this instead of an regular id ) isn't selected in the dropdown thats generated by an EntityType.

```php
->add('fuel1', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Chemical::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'required' => false,
            ])
```

```html
<option value="0e21313d-847e-4b8f-ab04-1cde3d0281e7">Chemical #1</option>
```

I expect the option to be selected. The value is correct in the DB, but it seems the data doesn't come through the EntityType.

** EDITTED, added some more code ****

```php
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
*/
private $fuel_1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add ['preferred_choices'](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#preferred-choices) in options, setting it to the entity id value if it's set

```php
->add('fuel1', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Chemical::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'required' => false,
                'preferred_choices' =>array($builder->getData()->getChemical()->getId() ?? null),
            ])
```

Comment: ```'preferred_choices' => $builder->getData()->getFuel1() ?? null ``` tried this, but in the `getFuel1()` there is an GUID string. My response right now is the following:
```Neither the property "837ad5d5-9ba0-4aa2-afd0-08ad2b964e55" nor one of the methods "get837ad5d5-9ba0-4aa2-afd0-08ad2b964e55()", "837ad5d5-9ba0-4aa2-afd0-08ad2b964e55()", "is837ad5d5-9ba0-4aa2-afd0-08ad2b964e55()", "has837ad5d5-9ba0-4aa2-afd0-08ad2b964e55()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "App\Entity\Chemical".```

Comment: `$builder->getData()->getFuel1()->getId()->toString()` should give you the uuid as string

Comment: ```dd("837ad5d5-9ba0-4aa2-afd0-08ad2b964e55")``` already returns ```"837ad5d5-9ba0-4aa2-afd0-08ad2b964e55"``` so thats in ID.

The value is the following in the Entity:

```/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $fuel_1;```

Comment: ```dd($builder->getData()->getFuel1())``` i mean, typo in the comment above.

Comment: if `$fuel_1` is a string, `EntityType::class` is not the right form field type: you should use `ChoiceType::class`, populate `choices` from the ChemicalRepository and set it as a special crafted array (i.e.: chemical name as key and GUID as value).
You should convert `$fuel_1` to a ManyToOne join with Chemical entity

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15837360/1139600 for another way to populate the ChoiceType